# CGAL - custom 2D point and intersection behavior in constrained delaunay triangulation

Tags: kernel, constraints, intersection, triangulation, cgal

In short, I have to generate a constrained delaunay triangulation from a set of 2D points that carry additional information.

Since there could be intersecting constraints, I need that the triangulation properly interpolates the satellite data whenever it generates the new point of intersection.

I tried with CGAL (C++) to define a custom kernel following the example [here](http://doc.cgal.org/latest/Kernel_23/index.html#Section_11.5), but I've failed to compile it succesfully, basically because there is something fundamental of the underlying generic programming machinery of CGAL that I am missing (lot of type mismatches etc.).

Can you point me to a working example that extends points with satellite data that is properly interpolated at constrain intersections (or at least something similar) ?

In theory, I could use a vertex with info, but then I'd need some callback mechanism that let me handle the intersection (I actually did this in a dirty way by modifying cgal source code). Anyway, what I am looking for is a "cgal-way" for achieving what I just discussed.

Comment: Is it an option to add your additional data into the vertex like in [this example](http://doc.cgal.org/latest/Triangulation_2/index.html#title40) rather than in the point?

Comment: @sloriot Yes it could be, and actually I already did it. But then I had to modify the original CGAL sources in the intersection function in order to interpolate vertex info, assuming that that info was done in a known way etc. In short, it could be an option but it is invalidated by the lack of a functor/callback/whatever that delegates you the interpolation/handling of vertex info at the newborn vertex.

Comment: If you use a Constrained_triangulation_plus_2, then you'll be able to iterate over sub-constraints and apply your interpolation

Comment: Can you post the code you made to create a custom kernel? We may be able to fix it.

Comment: Have you eventually found out a solution to your problem?

Comment: sorry I wasn't on SO for a long time.
after having abandoned the problem I finally reverted to another solution because I failed at any attempt to have it compiled.
in my humble opinion I think this could be an excellent example to provide alongside the documentation.